# How to close a jquery dialog box when a submit button is clicked(Submit button is residing inside the dialog box)

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts2, struts

i have struts2 form inside a jquery dialog box, when i submit my form inside that dialog box my Struts2 action is performing but that pop up jquery dialog box is not closing.

How can i close that dialog box when![enter image description here][1] i submit my form?

```
 <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <td align="center" >
                            <sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="cupertino" />

                            <sj:dialog 
                                id="mybuttondialog" 

                                autoOpen="false" 
                                showEffect="fadeIn" 
                                hideEffect="fadeOut" 
                                modal="true" 
                                title="Rename"
                                >
                                <s:form action="EditDayActionUserTemplate" id="formId323">
                                    <table style="height:48px;width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2"  align="center">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="dayId" value="<%=daycont%>"/> 
                                                <input type="hidden" name="workoutId" value="<%=trid%>"/> 
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="50%" align="right"><font size="6px">Date</font></td>
                                            <td width="50%"> <sj:datepicker id="datghfe4" name="date" value="%{#parameters['date']}" label="Select Date" appendText=" (dd.MM.yy)" displayFormat="dd.M.yy"/></td>
                                        </tr>   
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td align="right"><sj:submit formIds="formId323" id="sdfdss3" button="true" value="Rename" targets="rightmiddiv"></sj:submit></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                </s:form> 
                            </sj:dialog>
                            <sj:submit 
                                openDialog="mybuttondialog" 
                                value="Rename" 
                                button="true"

                                />
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need to close the dialog box (programmatically I suppose) call the dialog method with argument close. Like this

```
$('#mybuttondialog').dialog('close');
```

Check [this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) for more info.

Comment: i did it by --   $(function() {   
             $('#sdfdss3').click(function() {
$('#mybuttondialog').dialog('close');
});

} );